# "a due information"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Hamilton quickly focused on the last part of his opponent’s argument as support for his attempt to
>   introduce evidence of the truthfulness of his client’s publications. Hamilton offered the following
>   brilliantly ironic response:
>
> > Well, suppose it were so, and let us agree for once that truth is a greater sin than falsehood:
> >     Yet as the offenses are not equal, and as the punishment is arbitrary, that is, according as the
> >     judges in their discretion shall direct to be inflicted; is it not absolutely necessary that they
> >     should know whether the libel is true or false, that they may by that means be able to proportion
> >     the punishment? For would it not be a sad case if the judges, for want of **a due information**,
> >     should chance to give as severe a judgment against a man for writing or publishing a lie as for
> >     writing or publishing a truth? And yet this (with submission), as monstrous and ridiculous as it
> >     may seem to be, is the natural consequence of Mr. Attorney’s doctrine that truth makes a worse
> >     libel than falsehood, and must follow from his not proving our papers to be false, or not
> >     suffering us to prove them to be true.

Woudl someone please explain and elucidate **a due information**? The indefinite article "a" confuses me. Without it, I'd hazard the meaning of **due** to be:

[2. adjective: [attributive] Of the proper quality or extent](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/due?q=due).

Source: P38, *America on Trial* by Alan Dershowitz

Comment: I'd guess _an information_ here means _an act of being informed_. So _for want of a due information_ could be replaced by _because they have not been duly informed_.

Comment: In modern English, _information_ is almost always uncountable, but that was evidently not the case in the past.

Answer (score 1):

*Black's Law Dictionary* (1968) provides the following three definitions of *information*:

> **INFORMATION.** An accusation exhibited against a person for some criminal offense, without an indictment. [citation omitted] An accusation in the nature of an indictment, from which it differs only in being presented by a competent public officer on his oath of office, instead of a grand jury on their oath. [citations omitted] A written accusation sworm to before a magistrate upon which an indictment is afterwards founded. [citations omitted]

So "a due information" is an information—in one of the three senses listed here—that is required by law (that is, "due").

Answer (score 0):

Due also means "expected" - as "in due time" or "the result is due in two weeks" - so I would think *for want of a due information* means

> information not yet received

or just

> lack of relevant information

i.e. whether or not the target of the allegation was indeed guilty

Comment: I disagree that *due* in the example means not yet received (under, eg, senses 1 or 4 in [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/due#Adjective)) and prefer sense 2, appropriate or needful.